# Show min and max taxonomy values

Tags: taxonomy

I'm trying to get the min and max values from a taxonomy, but my code is returning all taxonomies:

```
function get_years ($taxonomies, $args){
$hlterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
foreach($hlterms as $term){
    $term_taxonomy = $term->year;
    $output .= $term->name;
} return $output;
}
$taxonomies = array ('year');
$args = array ('hide_empty'=>true);
$year = get_years($taxonomies, $args);
echo min(array($year));
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but try this:

```
  function get_years ($taxonomies, $args){
      $output = array();
      $hlterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
      foreach($hlterms as $term){
           $term_taxonomy = $term->year;
           array_push($output, $term->name);
     } return $output;
  }

$taxonomies = array ('year');
$args = array ('hide_empty'=>true);
$year = get_years($taxonomies, $args);
echo min($year);
```